# What do the colors and letter case of properties in the Chrome DevTools console indicate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

**Background**

The Chrome DevTools docs have [some information on what properties of different colors indicate](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom/properties/).

This does not seem to apply to ECMAScript object properties printed to the console.

As an example, `console.dir(window)` in Chrome DevTools' console will show the global object's properties. Chrome seems to categorize the properties into four categories here:

1. Uppercase properties
2. Lowercase properties
3. Bold properties
4. Light-color properties

**Screenshots**

Here are two screenshots for ease of reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Both bold and light-color properties come in lowercase and uppercase, so all combinations of the four formats are used.

**Question**

What does each of these four formats indicate, and is the behavior specified somewhere?

Comment: Case has no special meaning, those come from the actual property names, since property names are case-sensitive.

Comment: The uppercase vs. lowercase is not a category difference. It's just some of the properties have all upper-case names and others don't. `console.dir` appears to list things lexicographically, in which upper-case comes first, rather than (say) listing in object order.

Comment: Color represents the type of value (number, string, ...).

Comment: @Vucko - That's for the value, but notice that the actual property *name* is in bold or in a lighter color.

Comment: Apparently, the ligher ones are non-enumerable, the darker ones are enumerable. See: `const a = {}; Object.defineProperty(a, "x", {writable: true, value: "x", configurable: true, enumerable: false}); Object.defineProperty(a, "y", {writable: true, value: "y", configurable: true, enumerable: true}); console.dir(a);`